# send character to stdin of background Java process

Tags: java, process, background, pid

I am looking to send a character to a Java process running in the background. I found this article https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi?answertab=active#comment155464_178470 which I thought would solve the problem, but it actually doesn't. 
For testing purposes I added a line

```
 System.out.println("This is what I read "+(int)temp);
```

where temp is read this way

```
int temp = inputStreamReader.read();
```

Something really weird actually happens:

- I start the process in a terminal window (not in background this time)
- I open another terminal and look up the process' PID
- I run the command

  `echo q > /proc/*pid_of_the_process/fd/0`
- In the other window this line appears

  `q`

so for some reason I get to see this character in the terminal where the process is running, but it is actually not read by the process, because if that was the case then I would see this line

```
This is what I read 113
```

which is what I actually get if I type 'q' from within the terminal window.

Anybody knows why do I get this funny behavior?